# PocketBase API rule that allows anyone to count number of rows without returning field values

Tags: pocketbase

Is it possible to create a rule for the `List/Search` section that
will allow anyone to query the number of rows matching a certain
filter, but prevent the data (field values) from being viewed?

I have tried `@request.data.expand = []` but that shows as invalid.

I want anyone to be able to query the number of rows in my collection, without being able to read values.

Answer (score 1):

To [quote the creators](https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase/discussions/249#discussioncomment-3294273), you should implement aggregation (and the access layer for it) yourself:

> Aggregations and reporting is usually left to the users to do on their own using the internal DB abstraction.

If you have an application that communicates with PocketBase, a solution could be using [application hooks](https://github.com/pocketbase/js-sdk#send-hooks) to aggregate the data and return the appropriate response for the given user (collection rule would stay empty and `id = @request.auth.id` would have to be checked by your application to authorize data access).

If that does not satisfy your requirements and you need this to happen inside
of PocketBase, there are customizable [Collection API hooks](https://pocketbase.io/docs/event-hooks#collection-api-hooks) which you can take advantage of, in your case it will be `OnCollectionsListRequest` and `OnCollectionViewRequest`.